# printf - repeating arguments by format

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, printf

I've an array of strings (variable size...) like this:

```
arr=( "one str" "another str" "example" "last-string" )
```

I need the following output:

```
one str:one str another str:another str example:example last-string:last-string
```

The problem is that when i do something like:

```
$(printf " %s:%s" "${arr[@]}")
```

It iterates over the array, moving to next position of the string (without repeating!), and the result is like:

```
one str:another str  example:last-string
```

How can I achive this with printf? without any loops!

I'm using bash 3.1.0(1) in Cygwin if that helps!

Comment: I don't think that it is possible, without loops

Comment: If `printf` were built on POSIX `printf()`, you'd be able to use `printf '%1$:%1$s' abc def` to repeat things.  However, `bash` 4.x does not support that, so there's no reason to think `bash` 3.x will.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point! I don't know that it wasn't possible in bash 4.x...

Comment: @user000001 seems you were right... regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with bash's built-in `printf` function.  You'll either need to use a loop or an external program, e.g. Python:

```
# With a loop:
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
  printf " %s:%s" "$x" "$x"
done

# With Python
python -c 'import sys; print "".join(" %s:%s" % (arg, arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:])' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: yep, i can't find any other way to do this... i'll just go with a similar loop.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but you can try this:

```sh
arr=( "one str" "another str" "example" "last-string" )
intermediate_result=`printf " %s:%%s" "${arr[@]}"`
printf "$intermediate_result" "${arr[@]}"
```