# repeating a printf format in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to printf an array in bash, whose number of element is previously unknown.
so, the goal is to have something like:

```
printf  "latc= ${#latc[@]}%s\n" ${latc[@]}
```

but it does not seem to be possible.
I even tried solution of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621525/printf-repeating-arguments-by-format) as

```
for x in "${latc[@]}"
do
  printf " %s:%s\n" ${x}
done
```

, but I am not getting what I want.

currently I am working with:

```
printf  "       latc="
echo ${latc[@]}
```

clearly not an elegant method of doing thigs.
Any help please?

Comment: What do you want exactly? I can't quickly tell what you want to achieve by reading your post. Please post an explicit example of an array, and the output wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
printf "latc=%s\n" "${latc[*]}"
```

Quoting `${latc[*]}` produces a single string in which the elements of `latc` are joined using the first character of `IFS` (by default, a space). Quoting `${latc[@]}` induces a special expansion that produces one word for each element of the array. There is no way to indicate a repeated placeholder in the format string as you seemed to be trying with `${#latc[*]}%s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can print array as:

```
printf "%s\n" "${latc[@]}"
```